# Where are the energy losses here?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, renewable-energy, hydroelectric-dams

This hydroelectric system, described in [The Study of Syphon and Applied in Hydroelectricity Power Production](http://www.ijmerr.com/uploadfile/2018/1025/20181025024637556.pdf), is said to be continuous once it has been set up. Once set up it is claimed that it will continue to generate electricity without any additional external input.

[image: Hydroelectric system with a siphon setup]

I have seen similar devices in a couple of places. How does this work? I feel that as entropy increases, the process must stop. what am i missing here?

Comment: The siphon won’t work. That is easy enough for you to test - just need two buckets and a pipe.

Comment: I agree. The paper however shows results from this setup and says that "a continuous flow was established" and so I thought I'm missing something.

Comment: Unless that air pipe top right of tank is a valve that is shut…

Comment: they forgot to say `continuous flow until the tank is empty`

Comment: If this actually worked. Then you wouldnt publish this you would build one, then the next and soon corner the energy markets

Answer (score 1):

1. Siphons don't work uphill.
2. Any system that claims to be self-sustaining is not only wrong, but is prima facie wrong.  All you have to do is figure out where.